# MySQL Error 1064 - Am I blind? Strange error

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

My query:

```
UDPATE message_recipients SET
recipient_status = 2 WHERE mid = 3 AND
recipient_id = 4
```

Table fields:

id, mid, recipient_status, recipient_id

Error:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server
>   version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'UDPATE message_recipients SET
>   recipient_status = 2 WHERE mid = 3 AND
>   recipient_i' at line 1

Could someone give me any advice?

Comment: +1 Upvote for making me feel less embarrassed that I do this same thing frequently.

Comment: Shall i retag the question with ILLUSION

Comment: 99% of the time for `"...for the right syntax to use near 'quoted syntax'"` the first word in the quoted syntax will be the one at fault. I learned a long time ago to look very thoroughly at that first word before the rest.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need `UPDATE` instead of `UDPATE`.  I do this myself at least three times a week :)

Comment: @michael druaplity is really blind :-)

Comment: @zod I don't think he's blind. I make this error constantly when typing on the console.  Not so much in my text editor (vim) because I'm always calling the auto-complete after the first 1 or 2 characters and I notice problems in syntax highlighting.

Comment: +1 I even glossed over it on the first read. Reminds me of [this](http://www.snopes.com/language/apocryph/cambridge.asp).

Comment: @Joe Stefanelli I've seen that before -- on a poster inside a Jimmy John's sandwich shop.

Comment: Means I am blind. Anyway thank you :)